How to use ZurichBT-Roman/Univers/bun font with pdflatex (or lualatex) for text inside a Tikz node
As the title says, I'd liek to use ZurichBT-Roman/Univers/bun fonts with pdflatex (or lualatex) for text inside a Tikz node. How can we achieve this?

Your write-up isn't entire clear. Do you want this font to be used just inside a TikZ node? If so, which other font(s) will be used in the document, and should the working size of Zurich BT be adjusted to match some other font's size? Incidentally, since this font appears to be a TrueType font, you're much better off using LuaLaTeX to compile the document and the commands of the fontspec package to load the font. Please read the package's user guide to familiarize yourself with commands such as \newfontfamily (mentioned on page 9 of the user guide).
